# Only one UI item is shown by Silverlight Toolkit-Theming themes

Tags: c#, silverlight, themes

When I use any theme for more then one element I just can see one of them when I debug.

```
<toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
    <sdk:AutoCompleteBox
        SelectionChanged="AcBox_SelectionChanged"
        x:Name="AcBox"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="28"
        Margin="28,24,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="120">
    </sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
</toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
<--!-->
<toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
    <Button
        x:Name="Button1"
        Content="1000"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="White"
        Height="23"
        Width="100"/>
</toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
```

As you see I use it for both AutoComtplateBox and a button. I can't see both of them at the same time. Some people suggests that I can put both of them in one theme bricket insted of two. It says only one content can be put in it.
How can we use this theme for more than one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Panel`:

```
<toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
    <StackPanel>
        <sdk:AutoCompleteBox ... />
        <Button ... />
    </StackPanel>
</toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
```